# MD5 hashing for all fines in same directory - error no such file or directory

Tags: python, md5, file-not-found

I wouldlike to generate md5 for each file in directory but actually I have always the same problem :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_md5.py", line 43, in <module>
    generate_dir(argument_path)
  File "generate_md5.py", line 29, in generate_dir
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.xsd'
```

I don't understand where is the problem ?

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-idir', '--input_dir', help='directory', dest='path_dir_in')
argument_path = parser.parse_args()

    def generate_dir(argument_path):
        hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()

        for file in os.listdir(argument_path.path_dir_in):
            with open(file, "rb") as f:
                for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
                    hash_md5.update(chunk)
            print("Name :" + file)
            print(hash_md5.hexdigest())
            file_md5 = GenerateTxt()
            file_md5.write_file_txt([hash_md5.hexdigest()], file)
```

Comment: theres surely a dupe somewhere this comes up all the time ... os.listdir only returns the filename, not its directory so you need `os.path.join(argument_path.path_dir_in,filename)` ... also you should not use `file` as a variable name as it shadows the builtin (which probably doesnt break anything but is bad form)

Comment: oh ok thanks you I understood !

Comment: "file" is a builtin? Are we talking python2 or python3?

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.list.dir` to display all files and then `os.path.join` to open all files from directory :

```
def generate_dir(argument_path):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()

    for filename in os.listdir(argument_path.path_dir_in):
        with open(os.path.join(argument_path.path_dir_in, filename), "rb") as f:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
                hash_md5.update(chunk)
        print("Name :" + filename)
        print(hash_md5.hexdigest())
        file_md5 = GenerateTxt()
        file_md5.write_file_txt([hash_md5.hexdigest()], filename)
```

Comment: I would recommend the pathlib.Path() and pathlib.Path().iterdir() instead.